# Why do fluorescent microscopes employ a dichromatic mirror?

Tags: optics

I was looking into building a fluorescent microscope and this is the design everyone uses.

[image: fluorescence microscope]

But I'm wondering how come this design isn't used instead, using a shared light source for brightfield or fluorescence microscopy.

[image: fluorescence microscope2]

The only thing I can think of is the angle of reflected light and if we were trying to detect faint/low-concentration fluorophores, such as with fluorescent antibodies which could be bound to sparse cell membrane proteins.

If the fluorophore were to be illuminated from below, the majority of the emitted light would be reflected back down to the light source.

Standard brightfield microscopes use the specimen like a filter, filtering light into an image that we can observe. However, reflected light is also observable with a standard brightfield microscope, because plant cells are visibly green due to reflected green light, and we can see that under a brightfield microscope as well. It's just that there is enough reflected green light that some of it is randomly reflected back towards the detector.

However, it appears if you have a a bright fluorophore and enough of them, you can still see scattered emitted light. Such as shown here: http://makezine.com/2011/03/04/cheap-diy-gfp-green-fluorescent-protein-illuminator/

You could also try using higher intensity light source to brute force your way to enough scattered emitted light back, but it'd be limited by photobleaching and heating the sample/filters.

Overall, the commonly used design is more efficient? Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: Wouldn't synchronizing the positions of the illuminated spot and the observed spot be a big hassle with your design? With the standard design shown, after initial alignment of the optics, the observed spot would always coincide with the illuminated spot. Additionally, when the sample is in focus, the objective should also be directing a lot of illumination onto the sample. The standard design can also be used with either opaque of transparent samples whereas your design can only be used with transparent samples.

Comment: Hmm..... I'm trying to figure out why would the illuminated and observed locations be offset?

Comment: *Accidentally hit carriage return*. Hmm..... I'm trying to figure out why would the illuminated and observed locations be offset? (I'm going to keep thinking about this, but if all we've added to the brightfield microscope are two filters. Why would that change the angle/position of the light at the detector?) Illumination wise, if the condenser focuses the illumination, shouldn't it still be similar to if the objective focused the light onto the specimen? And I totally agree with the third point, it would only work on transparent samples. Definitely want to understand your points

Comment: Why should the illuminated and observed regions coincide for your design? For a microscope set to high-magnification, the region within the field-of-view may be only a few hundred microns in diameter or less. The illuminated spot size should be of similar diameter because any illumination outside of that diameter is wasted and cannot be seen. Now how do you adjust those two small spots so that they coincide in your design? For the standard design you showed, that alignment is almost automatic since the same objective is used for both observation and illumination.

Comment: Well, if what you're saying is true. Then the standard brightfield microscope design would also have issues with the illumination and observed regions coinciding. But this is a standard design that's capable of high magnification, without such problems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condenser_(optics)#Microscope_condenser Would introducing planar filters cause such problems? It seems unlikely

Comment: I'm guessing that for fluorescent microscopy that very intense illumination of the sample at the excitation wavelength is desirable. That can be achieved with the standard design you showed above, but getting that same level of intensity with brightfield illumination using a condenser may be very difficult. I'm not saying that it's impossible but that illumination focussing and alignment become very important to maximize the illumination intensity.

Comment: BTW, I just realized that I actually have a "fluorescent microscope" in my lab. I've never called it a "fluorescent microscope" but what it does is focus a 5 mW blue laser beam off a dichroic mirror and then through a microscope objective at a ruby chip in a diamond anvil cell. The wavelength of the red glow of the ruby is a function of the pressure in the cell. That red glow is captured by the objective, sent through a dichroic mirror and then to the microscope eyepiece or to a spectrometer. It works very well. Would be difficult to engineer and align it according to the second design, tho.

Comment: Without the condenser and just using collimated light it would have lower intensity of illumination (apparently they generally they use the condenser to improve the numerical aperture and resolution: http://zeiss-campus.magnet.fsu.edu/articles/basics/resolution.html).

Although for bright numerous fluorophores, illuminated and observed regions simply need to overlap as shown with this earlier rough setup: http://makezine.com/2011/03/04/cheap-diy-gfp-green-fluorescent-protein-illuminator/

Eh, might be difficult, but I guess worth a shot. We’ll see shortly! Thanks for your input!

Comment: Make sure that both filters are always in and are working as intended when doing alignment and operating the microscope. If the filters are removed, then there is a very bright focussed beam of light going straight through the microscope and to your eyes.

Comment: Yeah, the illumination source does tend to be fairly bright for these purposes. For me, it's going to be a camera at that end, but still don't want to melt the sensor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used a fluorescence microscope as in the first figure, it
was on samples that weren't transparent.   So, opaque
samples are one reason to use that geometry.

The dichroic mirror/filter in the first figure only has to reject
backscattered (diffuse) excitation illumination, but in the second has
to reject excitation light directed (focused) into (toward) the detector.

Instead of a fluorescence "emission" filter,
we detected the light through a grating spectrometer, and the exciting
illumination would have made stray-light contributions via internal
reflections if it were
directed into that device, as in the second figure above.   We only
required ONE filter (the dichroic mirror) rather than using two  plus the mirror.  The frequency-selective dichroic mirror subsumed the functions of the excitation filter and of the emission filter.

Comment: Ah yes that is true! Opaque samples would be an issue in the 2nd design. Luckily we're only dealing with transparent samples. Although to be more specific with the 2nd design setup, it would be lightSource>collimator>excitationFilter>condenser>sample>infinityCorrectedObjective>emissionFilter>tubeLens>"eyepieceLens">detector. So in this case, it should only be collimated light going through the filters rather than focused light which would likely melt the filters? Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, for our use we might need various combinations of emission/excitation filters.